# How can I get and set the description property of a SQL Server 2008 table using SMO?

Tags: c#, sql-server, smo

How can I get and set the description property of a SQL Server 2008 table using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo? I have seen documentation on how to do this at the column level but not at the table level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to do the following in powershell:

```
$s = new-object microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server '.';
$db = $s.Databases['AdventureWorks2012'];
$t = $db.Tables | where {$_.Name -eq 'Address'};
$t.ExtendedProperties['MS_Description']; # will print current value
$t.ExtendedProperties['MS_Description'].Value = 'new value';
$t.ExtendedProperties['MS_Description'].Alter(); #persist the new value to the database
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't remember:  Is the description in the Extended Properties?  If so, TableViewTableTypeBase.ExtendedProperties will have your description for you (which Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Table inherits)

Comment: I iterated over all of the ExtendedProperties but did not see it there.

Comment: Here's an example along the lines that I was thinking of (hoping this is what you were after, not sure) : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190243(v=sql.105).aspx.  Look for the part that is specific to tables where the code is `USE AdventureWorks2008R2; 
GO
EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty 
@name = N'MS_Description', 
@value = N'Street address information for customers, employees, and vendors.', 
@level0type = N'SCHEMA', @level0name = Person, 
@level1type = N'TABLE',  @level1name = Address;
GO`

Comment: Right, but it shows that this does appear to be the place for descriptions.  You could run a stored procedure like this EXEC all on a table and see what ends up in extend properties, then try and run through it from the C#/SMO side.

Comment: http://merill.net/2010/06/updating-extended-properties-of-a-database-using-sql-server-smo/

Answer (score 1):

It is in extended properties, I do it this way:

```
string Description = table.ExtendedProperties["MS_Description"].Value.ToString();
```

You need to specify which extended property you need in string - thats why you could not find it so easily.